# assert variable that can have different datatypes

Tags: python, string, assert

My `x` variable can be either string or int. This line of code does what I need

```
assert x == 'dummy_string' or x == 0
```

my concern is that I compare `x` variable against different datatypes. Can some unexpected problems arise because of that? Whouldn't it be better to always cast `x` to a string and do

```
assert x == 'dummy_string' or x == '0'
```

Is there any recommnedated way of doing that?

Comment: Assert takes a boolean value;  you're not passing it a string or an integer, you're passing it 'True' or 'False'

Comment: Since Python 3 does not have/use questionable coercion rules, `assert x == 'dummy_string' or x == 0` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

If `x` is always `str` or `int`, your first example should work fine without `TypeError`s or "Javascriptish" results like `'0' == 0`. By the way, comparison against multiple values can also be written like this:

```py
assert x in ('dummy_string', 0)
```

Otherwise, if you're afraid of `x` having some type that may raise `TypeError` from `__eq__()`, you can act extra defensive:

```py
assert (isinstance(x, str) and x == 'dummy_string') \
       or (isinstance(x, int) and x == 0)
```

I don't recommend checking for `str(x) == '0'` (your second example), because who knows, theoretically not only `int(0)` can stringize to `'0'`, but any class that defines:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return '0'
```